# How to register a bulk device

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I'm very new to Linux Kernel programming. I created a simple USB driver by reading [Greg's code](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/ldd-examples/usb/usb-skeleton.c); you can look at [my full code](http://kgcorner.com/code/simusb.c) if you want.

As far as I thought, this code can read data and write data from and to USB device.
But when I attached my pendrive I saw `dmesg` trace, I found everything okay but unable to find my device in output of `lsblk`.

As it's not there I'm not able to mount it and hence unable to test my driver.
Here's `dmesg` trace

```
[20073.437683] [SIMUSB]:Module Loaded
[20073.437730] [SIMUSB] USB Detected
[20073.437734] [SIMUSB] USB Vendor ID=1008 and Product ID=22023
[20073.437737] [SIMUSB] endpoint->bEndpointAddress=1
[20073.437740] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_DIR_OUT is 0
[20073.437743] [SIMUSB] ENDPOINT WITH OUT DIRECTION FOUND
[20073.437746] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bmAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK is 2
[20073.437749] [SIMUSB] OUT ENDPOINT adress set
[20073.437752] [SIMUSB] endpoint->bEndpointAddress=130
[20073.437755] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_DIR_IN is 128
[20073.437757] [SIMUSB] ENDPOINT WITH IN DIRECTION FOUND
[20073.437760] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bmAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK is 2
[20073.437763] [SIMUSB] IN ENDPOINT adress set
[20073.437910] [SIMUSB] status=0
[20073.437914] [SIMUSB] USB Registered Successfully
```

Just added one line after `usb_register_dev()` in `sim_prob`

> printk(KERN_INFO "[SIMUSB] retval=%d",retval);

I get following output of command `demsg|grep SIMUSB`

```
root@anandlinux:/lin_dev/kprogs/usb_rough# dmesg|grep SIMUSB
[7803.843992] [SIMUSB]:Module Loaded
[7803.844055] [SIMUSB] USB Detected
[7803.844060] [SIMUSB] USB Vendor ID=2385 and Product ID=5699
[7803.844064] [SIMUSB] endpoint->bEndpointAddress=129
[7803.844069] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_DIR_IN is 128
[7803.844073] [SIMUSB] ENDPOINT WITH IN DIRECTION FOUND
[7803.844077] [SIMUSB] Result of endpoint->bmAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK is 2
[7803.844080] [SIMUSB] IN ENDPOINT adress set
[7803.844085] [SIMUSB] endpoint->bEndpointAddress=2
[7803.844089] [SIMUSB] OUT ENDPOINT adress set
[7803.844156] [SIMUSB] retval=0
[7803.844186] [SIMUSB] status=0
[7803.844188] [SIMUSB] USB Registered Successfully
root@anandlinux:/lin_dev/kprogs/usb_rough#
```

Comment: Cannot access your code. Please post a valid link or post your code here.

Comment: What's the return value of usb_register_dev() in function sim_prob() ? Can you print it and update it here ? Please check the return values in your code.

Comment: What version of the kernel are you running ? 'uname -r" ? Which distro ?

Comment: Please see updated post.. i mentioned retval's value... i'm using kubuntu kernel version in 3.11 rc2

Answer (score 0):

You are only registering the device with the USB layer. This doesn't allow you to mount the filesystem or the device unless you also register the device with the SCSI layer. Run `lsusb` to see your device. `lsblk` won't show it as it is not registered with the block layer.

Read this documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scsi/scsi_mid_low_api.txt to know about SCSI layer API's

Also, go through `drivers/usb/storage/usb.c` in the kernel source tree. This is the generic `usb-storage` driver that works with most of the usb drives. Go through the storage_probe function. You can see that it makes a call to `usb_stor_probe1` and `usb_stor_prob2` functions. These functions are exported and as such you can use them in your probe function provided you have the usb-storage module built into the kernel image you are linking to and also have the headers that declare them.

For an example of how to use the above two functions, see `drivers/usb/storage/alauda.c alauda_probe` function. You can do something on similar lines. This file is present in the same directory in the kernel source as the usb-storage driver. You might also have to do the same if you want to use these functions.

NOTE: If you have `usb-storage` module loaded, then it will claim your device and your drivers probe function won't be called. You might mimic the functionality present there in your driver or find ways of getting your driver to claim your device.